# How do you "declare" a global struct?

Tags: c++, struct, global

I've a .h file that declare 3 different/similar class:

```
#ifndef _ICUSTOMCONTROLS_
#define _ICUSTOMCONTROLS_

class ICustomKnob1 : public IKnobControl
{
private:
    // ..

public:
    // ..
};

class ICustomKnob2 : public IControl
{
private:
    // ..

public:
    // ..
};

class ICustomButton : public IButtonControl
{
private:
    // ..

public:
    // ..
};

#endif // !_ICUSTOMCONTROLS_
```

I've a cpp file that define these class. I include the .h in the cpp and also in other .h/.cpp files within the project (which is a DLL).

At this point, in the CPP, I'd like to use a common/global struct (`IText`) for all the 3 classes. If I add the declaration in the .h:

```
IText gTextCustomControl;
```

in fact it "define" it, so I got a `LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found` error message on compiling (as I said, I add this .h many times).

I could add it (with real definition) in the .cpp file:

```
IText gTextCustomControl = IText(12, &COLOR_WHITE, "Arial", IText::kStyleBold, IText::kAlignCenter, 0, IText::kQualityDefault);
```

But I will never sure in the DLL when this will be "processed" (maybe later the CTOR of the classes? maybe more times, wasting resources?). I don't think is a good way.

I could add extern as well on .h and define it as above, but for security reason is even worse (someone could access from the "extern" to it).

How would you manage this situation? Or its not possible share a common struct across objects?

Comment: What is the reason to create global instance of an interface? I hope it's good (:

Comment: "security". No, `extern` does not affect security.

Comment: That you want to do this in a DLL is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bt I will never sure in the DLL when this will be "processed" (maybe later the CTOR of the classes?"

This is indeed the correct concern. DLL globals will be constructed from `DllMain`, and `DllMain` is ***heavily*** restricted in what it can do. You can't load other DLL's from there (loader lock), or do anything that would force Windows to load other DLL's. So using functions from other DLL's is generally also banned (exception: if your A.DLL causes your B.DLL to be loaded, then B.DLL may call functions from A.DLL. ).

Correct solution:

```
IText& getTextCustomControl();
...
IText& getTextCustomControl() {
   static IText retval (12, &COLOR_WHITE, "Arial", IText::kStyleBold,
                 IText::kAlignCenter, 0, IText::kQualityDefault);
   return retval;
}
```

This initializes the object on the first call to `getTextCustomControl`, which in general will happen way after all `DllMain()` functions have finished.

Comment: But this means that every time I call it, it "creates" a new intance and return it :( Isn't a waste of resource?

Comment: @paizza: Sorry, my bad - edited. I didn't know whether it would be a waste of resources, so I was flip-flopping between a `static` (in which case you return `IText&`) and a local variable (in which case you'd return `IText`)

Comment: I mean: every time I call getTextCustomControl it will create a new object within the stack :O And return its adress. Istead, I'd like a shared object from stack...

Comment: @paizza: There is no such thing as a shared object from stack, but this is a shared object and will only be created once. Look up what `static` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the global variable inside the .cpp, there is no guarantee that it will be initialized prior to other global variables (see *§3.6.3/2 [basic.start.dynamic]*), in particular:

```
// dll.cpp

IText gTextCustomControl = ...;

ICustomKnob2::ICustomKnob2 () {
    gTextCustomControl.doSomething();
}

// main.cpp

ICustomKnob2 knob2; // Oops! gTextCustomControl may be initialized after this.
```

If you want to be sure that `gTextCustomControl` initialized when you need it, you could put its declaration inside a function or some kind of singleton class, e.g.:

```
IText& get_gTextCustomControl () {
   static IText ins(12, &COLOR_WHITE, "Arial", IText::kStyleBold, 
                    IText::kAlignCenter, 0, IText::kQualityDefault);
   return ins;
}
```

Then you use it instead of the global variable, this will ensure that the instance is constructed before any use of it.

```
ICustomKnob2::ICustomKnob2 () {
    get_gTextCustomControl().doSomething();
}
```

Obviously, this will delay the construction of `gTextCustomControl` to its first use, which may not be what you want.

Comment: "Oops! gTextCustomControl may be initialized after this." Even if dll.h (thus dll.cpp) is included at the top of main.cpp? (so "before" ICustomKnob2 knob2;)?

Comment: @paizza Include a `.hpp` does not "include" a .cpp or .dll. The .dll is "linked" to the main program by the linker, and this happens after the compilation of your various translation units. Once you everything is linked together, the order in which each global variables are instantiated is mostly implementation defined (even inside the same translation unit).

Comment: @Holt: _except_ inside the same translation unit, where instantiation order is definition order.

Comment: @MSalters That's what I thought, but as far as I understanding it, the example in 3.6.2/3.2 seems to say the opposite (correct me if I am wrong): *"if the initialization of an object obj1 refers to an object obj2 of namespace scope potentially requiring dynamic initialization and defined later in the same translation unit, it is unspecified whether the value of obj2 used will be the value of the fully initialized obj2 (because obj2 was statically initialized) or will be the value of obj2 merely zero-initialized.*"

Comment: @MSalters The relevant part of the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static (example at the bottom). I did not want to mean "the opposite" actually, but what you say seems not to hold in some case (again, correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: @Holt: I initially quoted your imprecise "instantiation order" which isn't Standardese. There's a definition order (literal order of definitions in code) and an initialization order (temporal, at execution time). The initialization order includes the zero-initialization / static initialization and dynamic initializations. Now the problem is that dynamic initialization _might_ introduce yet another order. For dynamic initialization, the initializer expressions may depend on other globals. This forms a acyclic (!) dependency graph with yet another order. _That_ order really messes things up.